# Android, difference between LongPress Home and Home

Tags: android

In my app, I've noticed a difference when using the home button.

Ex.
I press app icon, and the app starts op like it should with Activity(A). When I press Home button, the app gets minimized as it should. When I press app icon again, the app resumes with onResume() with Activity(A)

Now for the tricky part.
From the app, when I press my "Start button" another Activity(B) is launched, and focus is changed to the new Activity(B). When I press Home, the app minimizes (like its supposed to).

And now for the problem:
If I press the app icon, my app starts op from the very beginning with Activity(A) where my start button is. (And not with ActivityB which I just minimized)
If I do the scenario over again (Start app - > focus to Activity(B) -> Press home) and this time long press the home button, and the "Recently launched" comes op, and I select my app. Now the focus resumes to Activity(B)

Both Activity(A) and Activity(B) are set to SingleTop.

My question is, why is there a difference when using the different combinations of LongPress home + icon and OneClick Home + icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   First think about this... when you are opening your application ...
   your first Screen will be shown may be it is SplashScreen.

   and if..you are in Activity A and goes to B and then Press BACK obviously
   you will see Activity A.
```

So now when you *Long Press Home button*..That **shows you recent apps** with saves state of last shown Activity..that's why when you open from there..you see Activity B directly without SplashScreen.

And *Simple Pressing Home Button Once*,you are went to Home Screen from where you are opening Applications Screen which is **Launcher Screen**..from there If you press any Icon that particular app will be Launched(*Means to open the app from its Main Activity that is defined in Manifest with Intent Filter set to Launcher*)...That's why opening an app from there will always show you,your SplashScreen.

```
This is not a Bug,not an Issue..This is how the Android is designed to work.
```

Same button is used to perform two different events,cause they are related..but It's not like both event performs the same actions.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing to the above scenario, I have an App with Login Screen which takes me to Activity A -> OnClick of some button takes me to Activity B.
when there is a LongPress of Homebutton,and I start another App and stay on it for considerable time like say 5-10 minutes. Then again When i Long Press home button, and return to my Activity - It starts with Activity B .. which is correct.
From Activity B if i press Back key, It does take me to Activity A but there is a Black screen shown. In normal cases, It shows me a a list view of Dynamic XML data.